# Javascript form validation (decimal places)

Tags: javascript

I am using the following script to validate a form and would like to be able to to ensure that the inputter correctly inputs a numeric value with decimal places on the last field (amount).

Can anyone help with this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function validate()
{
   if( document.create_invoice.job_no.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide a Job No" );
     document.create_invoice.job_no.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
   if( document.create_invoice.contact.value == "-1" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide a Customer Contact" );
     return false;
   }
   if( document.create_invoice.employee.value == "-1" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide an Employee" );
     return false;
   }
   if( document.create_invoice.invoice_no.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide an Invoice No" );
     document.create_invoice.invoice_no.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
   if( document.create_invoice.address.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide an Address" );
     document.create_invoice.address.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
   if( document.create_invoice.amount.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide an Amount" );
     document.create_invoice.amount.focus() ;
     return false;
   }
}
//-->
</script>
```

Thanks,

John

Comment: Can you use Regular expressions? It will make easier the numeric validation, or you can do a try{ parseFloat( valueString )}

Comment: @Edorka - I know nothing about Javascript, I got the above code from a tutorial. Could you show me how to achieve this please? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use  parseFloat() for that... Try :

```
if( parseFloat(document.create_invoice.amount.value) != document.create_invoice.amount.value )
{
   alert( "Please provide a decimal value" );
   document.create_invoice.amount.focus() ;
   return false;
}
```

That might just do the trick for you.

Comment: Thanks @rtome. I pasted that at the bottom just under the last return false; } but it did nothing i'm affraid.

Comment: How are you calling your validate function ?

Comment: I've tried it and it works for me. 

See a test here http://jsbin.com/donek/1/

Comment: Sorry all, it was me - works fine. Thank you.